# Est-ce qu'on utilise un verbe à l'infinitif après "je suis sûr que ... seront..."?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

Je suis en train de lire la [lettre d'acception d'une offre d'emploi](http://www.dormirenfrance.fr/comment-accepte-s107205.htm). J'ai eu un problème avec le paragraphe suivant:

> Je suis enthousiasmé par la perspective de contribuer au grand succès
>   de l'entreprise a eu et nous réjouissons de cette opportunité. Vous
>   vous souviendrez que mon expérience inclut les ventes, le marketing et
>   gestion des entreprises. **Je suis sûr que mes compétences seront bien
>   traduire à l'excellent environnement chez XYZ.**

---

Est-ce cela vous semble correct? pourquoi **traduire** est à l'infintif?

Comment: google translate, anyone? John Doe? C'est  horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the link you posted.

The French used there is extremely broken. You should really forget about this page which was probably built using Google Translate or something similar. There are too many grammar mistakes and barely understandable sentences. The specific one you mention is one of these, along with the whole paragraph.

Here is an attempt to salvage it:

> Je suis enthousiasmé par la perspective de contribuer au grand succès de l'entreprise a eu et nous réjouissons de cette opportunité.

*Je suis très heureux de la perspective de contribuer au succès de votre entreprise et me réjouis de cette opportunité.*

> Vous vous souviendrez que mon expérience inclut les ventes, le marketing et gestion des entreprises.

*Je me permet de vous signaler que mon expérience inclut les ventes, le marketing et la gestion des entreprises.*

> Je suis sûr que mes compétences seront bien traduire à l'excellent environnement chez XYZ.

*Je suis sûr que mes compétences seront bien adaptées à l'excellent environnement de XYZ.*

Comment: @jilliagre est-ce c'est possible d'ajouter **C'est un challenge très intéressant** avant ***et Je suis sûr que mes compétences seront bien adaptées à l'excellent environnement de XYZ.***

Comment: too bad the workplace is only in english